# Multi-database support in Realtime database. Is there a limit?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

Since almost 1 year it is possible to have multiple realtime databases in a firebase project.
https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/11/easier-scaling-with-multi-database.html

In order to figure out how well a backend would scale in terms of concurrent connections (100.000 per database) i need to know whether there is a limitation on the number of databases per project?

Comment: This is a great question for Firebase support.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: good idea! Thank you.